# What is the cardinal $\aleph_2^{\aleph_1}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm looking for the cardinality of the set of functions : $$\mathbb{R}\rightarrow F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$$

Where the latter is the set of all functions from the reals to the reals.

Is it : $$\aleph_2^{\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_1\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$$ ?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $2^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_{n+1}$; that [isn't provable from the usual axioms of set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis#The_generalized_continuum_hypothesis).

Comment: It depends upon your set theory axioms. There are axioms that settle the GCH (Generalised Continuum Hypothesis) and so would settle this question.

Answer (score 3):

*Following the OP, below I'll write "$F(A,B)$" for the set of functions from $A$ to $B$.*

---

You seem to be assuming that $\vert\mathbb{R}\vert=\aleph_1$ and $\vert\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}\vert=\aleph_2$ - or perhaps more snappily, that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ and $2^{(2^{\aleph_0})}=\aleph_2$. This is **not** provable from the usual axioms of set theory alone - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis#The_generalized_continuum_hypothesis).

However, modulo this you are correct: the cardinaity of the set in question is indeed $2^{(2^{\aleph_0})}$, or more snappily [$\beth_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number). This can be informally motivated by $$\vert F(\mathbb{R}, F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}))\vert= ((2^{\aleph_0})^{2^{\aleph_0}})^{2^{\aleph_0}}=2^{\aleph_0\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}}=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}.$$

Of course this sort of manipulation requires justification: we have to argue that cardinal exponentiation matches up with function set formation, and that cardinal exponentiation follows the appropriate basic rules. If you haven't seen these, rigorously interpreting and justifying the above calculation is a good exercise.

Comment: Is it correct to say : $F(\mathbb{R},F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}))=F(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: @JulienPitteloud It depens what you mean by "$=$" there. There's certainly a canonical bijection - it's just [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) - but they're not literally the same set.